# Cmake. Unnormal behaviour

Tags: c++, cmake

Let's consider two simplified `CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(GTEST "/usr/local/lib/libgtest.a")
set(GMOCK "/usr/local/lib/libgmock.a")
...
target_link_libraries(project  ${GTEST} ${GMOCK})
```

And  when I `cmake` and then `make` it works. However, the following doesn't work:

```
set(GTEST "/usr/local/lib/libgtest.a  /usr/local/lib/libgmock.a")
...
target_link_libraries(project  ${GTEST})
```

When I put `cmake` it works OK. But when I put make it gives me:

```
make[3]: *** There is no rule for '/usr/local/lib/libgtest.a /usr/local/lib/libgmock.a'
```

Why?

Comment: Looks like you have an extra double quote in the second example.

Comment: I edited. I was not a problem. I just made a mistake when I wirite a post.

Comment: You should be copy/pasting verbatim when you compose your post. How are we to know that you did not make other such transcription errors?

Comment: I don't understand why this is "unnormal" behaviour. Why would you expect this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two examples do not mean the same thing. The first example passes two libraries to `target_link_libraries`. The second one passes one library name with two spaces in it. If you want to pass two libraries in one variable, use

```
set(GTEST "/usr/local/lib/libgtest.a" "/usr/local/lib/libgmock.a")
```

As to why the failure is such a strange message, I suspect missing escaping on CMake's part (though your path would have a directory name with a trailing space in it, which probably won't occur in practice).

Comment: ok, so: `set` makes variable which is string in our case. I understand that `target_link_libraries` assumes that there will be exactly one library ( path to one library) in passed variable!?

Comment: As stated in my answer, you can pass multiple values (that is, a list of values) in a single variable to `target_link_libraries`. But a quoted space is not interpreted as a separator in CMake (in fact, a semicolon `;` is: `set(foo "bar" "baz")` is the same as `set(foo "bar;baz")`).